# Flattening a nested list in Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am facing some difficulty flattening parts of a nested list in Python.
Here is the list:

```
[['31', '1'], '32', ['8', '16'], ['1', '3', '12'], ['4', '12'], '32', ['1', '3', '12'], ['4', '12'], '32', ['30', '1', '1']]
```

I want to flatten any lists inside of that list with the end result looking like this:

```
['31', '1', '32', '8', '16', '1', '3', '12', '4', '12', '32', '1', '3', '12', '4', '12', '32', '30', '1', '1']
```

From looking up ways to do this I tried this code:

```
list1 = (list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list1)))
```

However, it not only flattens the lists but also the individual strings, splitting any string with more than 1 character (i.e. '32' becomes '3', '2') looking like this:

```
['31', '1', '3', '2', '8', '16', '1', '3', '12', '4', '12', '3', '2', '1', '3', '12', '4', '12', '3', '2', '30', '1', '1']
```

Is there a way to flatten only the lists inside of this list and not the individual strings? Sorry if the terminology is incorrect, I am not too familiar with manipulating this kind of list. Thank you!

Comment: All you need is numpy.hstack to flatten the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [['31', '1'], '32', ['8', '16'], ['1', '3', '12'], ['4', '12'], '32', ['1', '3', '12'], ['4', '12'], '32', ['30', '1', '1']]

def extract(array):
    for item in array:
        if type(item) in [set, list, tuple]:
            yield from extract(item)
            continue
        yield item

print(list(extract(arr)))  # ['31', '1', '32', '8', '16', '1', '3', '12', '4', '12', '32', '1', '3', '12', '4', '12', '32', '30', '1', '1']
```

Comment: Great use of a generator!  @Kush S. you can convert the result of `extract` to a list by doing `list(extract(...))`

Comment: What is the syntax to extract when the list is as such? `[['Alexia', 60], ['Alissa', 30], ['Shane', 20], ['Grace', 24]]`